# Why is C++ backward compatible with C ? Why isn't there some "pure" C++ language?

Tags: c++, c, history

C and C++ are different languages, blababla we know that.

But if those language are different, why is it still possible to use function like malloc or free ? I'm sure there are all sort of dusty things C++ has because of C, but since C++ is another language, why not remove those things to make it a little less bloat and more clean and clear ?

Is it because it allows programmers to work without the OO model or because some compilers doesn't support high-level abstract features of C++ ?

Comment: A little C++ history: http://www.hitmill.com/programming/cpp/cppHistory.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

About "Why there's no "pure" C++ language... Well, there is at least one. The most popular one is called D, it's great, well-designed, feature-rich, pleasant to code with, and you can use C libraries with it.

Ah, and almost nobody uses it. :)

The direct reason is that C++ is not bad enough to give people a good reason to port millions of lines of their legacy code to more modern, and as you described, "pure" languages like D.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the relationship between C and C++ and instead plugs another language.

Comment: Well, there's the second part of the question which I directly related to.

Comment: D is interesting, but I wouldn't call it a "pure C++" ... it's a different language with many of the same goals and without the legacy C baggage.

Comment: @dajames: It sounds like exactly like what the OP is asking for though.

Answer (score 26):

Because C++ would be right out dead if it wouldn't be compatible to C the way it is now. No one, except the fanbois, would like C++ if it wouldn't be compatible to C. (I know I'm probably going to be downvoted for this. Be it so!).

Comment: @Johannes: I have to disagree. Languages like Java and C# got off the ground just fine without any direct C compatibility like C++ has.

Comment: Umm, C# has all the basic form of C - and I'd say that goes a long way towards its popularilty.  It's the main reason I use it over Java...

Comment: @Michael: You can cut all the dust and crud from C++ while keeping the basic form of C. Being a C-family language is not the same as C++'s direct compatibility with C.

Comment: @Michael I can't see how you can distinguish C# and Java on that particular issue.

Comment: @DeadMG C# and Java don't have the [issues that C++ has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385297/whats-wrong-with-c-compared-to-other-languages). The bill for C++ is easy: Direct support for C, for the price of having #include files, undefined behavior and similar weirdness. If you cut off the former, the latter is paid to no avail.

Comment: @DeadMG: Java and C# are generally not suited for systems programming - apples and oranges, my friend...

Comment: Java's killer app was write-once-run-anywhere, c#'s was easy application development on Windows. C++'s killer app was do the same system programming you'd have done in c but with object orientation. Different markets.

Comment: @Johannes: I have to disagree. C++ offers more than just C with Classes. Templates are far more powerful than generics in either languages, for example. In my opinion, half the cause of problems in C++ is that it tries to be ultraportable, which is pretty meaningless cause you can't exactly take a GUI program for Win32 and make it run on an embedded processor with no changes anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: I could not care less for GUI programming :) Anyway C++ (probably) took off spectacularly because C-interaction was so easy: care to name a language where exporting a C-compatible interface is as easy as using `extern "C" { ... }` ? This meant that one could use existing C libraries and plug C code in C++ fairly easily. Now don't take me wrong, as a daily C++ user, I've come to loathe a number of C-isms (and undefined behavior is certainly amongsts my personal peeves), but you just cannot remake history.

Comment: @DeadMG I have no idea what this has to do with C++ having templates. I don't think D can be seen as still being C++, so I'm not going to mention it here. But imagine we just change the syntax, but keep the semantics as is (that is, keep include files, undefined behavior etc pp). Like, replace "int" by "num". Noone would like the resulting language. Just take a look at the popularity of [SPECS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significantly_Prettier_and_Easier_C%2B%2B_Syntax). I'm sorry, I sense a fanboi mentality in your comments!

Comment: @Matthieu: GUI programming is just an example - there are some things that you just can't abstract away and most programs are not designed to run on every platform with a Standard-compliant compiler. @Johannes: Why, I might like C++ because I find C# and Java especially have very poor generics. I also dislike the way that you MUST program how the language designers intended, instead of how you want to- notably the lack of "friend" in Java and no private virtuals in C#, for example. I'm not arguing that C++ doesn't have plenty of it's own problems- but it didn't cut some perfectly good things.

Answer (score 8):

Most operating systems expose a C API, so if you want to use C++ for systems programming, you need some level of C interoperability.

That the C standard library was incorporated into the C++ standard library has historical and practical reasons: C++ began its life as an extension of C, and the C standard library was ready to use. It would be silly to exclude part of the library (like `malloc` and `free`) just because there are more idiomatic C++ alternatives: if you want to do stupid things, C++ gives you the power to do so.

For actual language semantics, the same applies - but to a lesser degree - and because of backwards-compatibility, C++ can never be entirely free of its C heritage.

Answer (score 7):

It's designed so that you can port C code and compile it as C++ code directly, and it allows for incremental upgrading of existing code. If C++ didn't have malloc/free, you couldn't compile existing C code as C++, because you'd have to pay some poor shmuck to go through and find all the malloc calls and replace them, which is expensive.

Comment: Nit picked: C++ doesn't *have* `malloc` and `free`, it *supports* them, because they are part of the c standard library not language keywords. But either way an important point.

Answer (score 5):

C++ was designed to be compatible with C -- in fact it was originally a superset of C, but the C language has since changed to break that.

This means that C libraries -- including the C run-time library -- can be called from C++ code. It does **not** mean that it is a good idea to do so!

If you want a "pure" C++ then you can just use C++ without calling any C libraries.

[As others have said since I started typing this: The Design & Evolution of C++ is a good place to start reading for the background on this.]

Comment: Note that it was never a pure superset of C -- there are a few minor differences due to keywords, the sizeof a character literal, etc.

Comment: Oh.. sizeof a character literal? what has changed with that?

Comment: char is int in c.  `sizeof(char)` is 4 in c, but 1 in c++.

Comment: @Tim: No, `sizeof(char)` is 1 in C too.  It's `'c'` that's of type `int` in C, but type `char` in C++; thus `sizeof('c')` is 4 in C but 1 in C++.

Comment: There`s a good discussion under the head "COMPATIBILTY ISSUES" in the C++ Programming Language - Stroustrup.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at [The Design & Evolution of C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) to get a better feel for the reason the language turned out the way it is. There are historical reasons why C++ grew out of C and was made backward compatible with it.

Answer (score 3):

The early versions of C++ were built on top of C and in fact the compiler translated C++ code to C which was in turn compiled by the local C compiler. Bjarne Stroustrup is a great believer in backwards compatibility and would, I'm sure, resist any attempt to take functionality away.

You can read all about in in Bjarne's book [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Evolution-C-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0201543303).

Answer (score 1):

There were plenty of more pure languages.  They didn't get widely used, though, because they were too far outside the comfort range of most programmers.  C++, on the other hand, allowed programmers to slowly ramp up by allowing C styles.

What you're doing is looking at languages like C# or Python and wondering why C++ doesn't look like them, but forgetting that getting there required stepping stones like C++ and Java, or Awk and Perl.

To adapt a quotation I heard earlier: C# is Microsoft's version of Sun's for-idiots version of Bell's version of C-enhanced-by-Simula.

Answer (score 1):

All are right. To sum up: the reason is **politics**. If you want something to be popular, enhance something already popular and you have a ready market. Design something new and no one will be interested unless you are Sun, design some utter crap, but throw billions of dollars into library development and marketing.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` and `free()` are required so that you can call into C language libraries from C++ code.  The C language library might return a pointer to memory allocated with `malloc()` that must be freed by the caller with `free()`; or, less commonly, it might require a pointer to memory allocated with `malloc()` that it can internally reallocate with `realloc()` or free with `free()`.