# Is it better to include <cassert> or <assert.h>?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using C++11, is it better to `#include` `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>`?  Or is there no difference?

Edit:

It seems [Should I include <xxxx.h> or <cxxxx> in C++ programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889467/should-i-include-xxxx-h-or-cxxxx-in-c-programs) argues that it comes down to polluting the global namespace.  Is this a special case because `assert` is a macro and there is no `std::assert`?

Comment: [Should I include stddef.h or cstddef for size_t](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5079325/995714), [Difference between string.h and cstring?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8380805/995714), [What's the main difference between stdlib.h and cstdlib in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2847729/995714)

Comment: @TallBrianL. As I stated in my answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011737/is-it-better-to-include-cassert-or-assert-h/43011792?noredirect=1#comment73114058_43011792. Neither is wrong, if you use assert.h your program will be backwards compatible with C, if you use cassert, it will definitely not be.

Comment: *@Santiago Varela* But C backwards compatible C++ code? How is that a thing? Backwards compatible C++ code is probably atrocious C++. Even the usual trivial hello world example uses `cout` which does not exist in C. In practice using the C-style include won’t gain you anything in terms of overall compatibility.

Comment: @besc There is tons and tons of C legacy code. A lot of low level and older systems are coded in C.  **C++ and C interoperability/portability** has been and will still be vitally important. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575192/why-is-c-backward-compatible-with-c-why-isnt-there-some-pure-c-language

Comment: *@Santiago Varela* I’m not questioning interoperability. Especially compiling C as C++ can be incredibly useful. And where would we be without C API layers to glue the world together? What I’m saying is: If you restrict your C++ to the C-compatible subset, then the language you write in is not C++ anymore, it’s C. At that point the question becomes moot because in C the choice between cassert and assert.h does not exist.

Comment: C is no longer a subset of C++ anyway.

Comment: I almost voted to reopen as `<cassert>` is distinctly different than the other standard headers in that it defines only macros (which can't be limited to a namespace), but after reading the answers to both questions that distinction doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The contents of `<cassert>` are the same as the C standard library header `<assert.h>`, except that a macro named `static_assert` is not defined.<sup>1</sup>

Prefer `<cassert>`.

All of the `<xxx.h>` C headers (including `<assert.h>`) are deprecated:

**D.5 C standard library headers [depr.c.headers]**

**Update regarding the `static_assert` macro from C**

In D.5 [depr.c.headers], the C++ standard refers to the `<xxx.h>` headers as "the *C headers*:

> 1 For compatibility with the C standard library, the C++ standard library provides the *C headers* shown in Table 141.

In C++14, the specification referenced C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999).  C99 did not define the macro `static_assert` (in any header).  C++14 had this to say about `<cassert>` in 19.3 [assertions]:

> 2 The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<assert.h>`.

C++17 references C11 (SO/IEC 9899:2011) which *does* define `static_assert` in `<assert.h>`, and has this to say about `<cassert>` in 22.3.1 [cassert.syn]:

> 1 The contents are the same as the C standard library header `<assert.h>`, except that a macro named `static_assert` is not defined.

Both C++14 and C++17 define `<assert.h>` only by reference to their respective C specifications, and also by this:

> See also: ISO C 7.2.

(which is the C section that specifies `<assert.h>`)

The way I read this, *techincally* `<assert.h>`, when compiled with a C++17 compiler, actually *does* define a macro named `static_assert`.  However doing so would be pointless, and I can't imagine that any implementation actually bothers to do so.

In any event, I stand by my recommendation above:

> Prefer `<cassert>`.

It's just the C++ way to do things.  And at least in C++98/03/11/14/17, it avoids depending on deprecated functionality.  Who knows what C++20 will bring.  But C++20 definitely will not deprecate `<cassert>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> **22.3.1 Header  synopsis [cassert.syn]**

<sup>2</sup> [Link to the C++11 specification.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)

<sup>3</sup> [Link to the C++17 specification.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4660.pdf)

Comment: There is a proposal to undeprecate the C headers (I bet you are aware, but not everyone will be): http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r0.html#3.5

Comment: @Sjoerd:  Excellent comment!  This is a proposal for C++20.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading, as it uses "C standard library header" to refer to C's version of `<assert.h>`, and then the same term to refer to C++'s version of it. To be clear, C defines a macro named `static_assert` in `<assert.h>`. C++ defines no such macro in either `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>`.

Comment: "Both C++14 and C++17 define `<assert.h>` only by reference to their respective C specifications" -- [depr.c.headers]p2 is what states that C++'s `<assert.h>` is defined in terms of `<cassert>`, which in turn is defined in terms of C's `<assert.h>`. Since `<cassert>` lacks a `static_assert` macro and there is nothing adding it back to C++'s `<assert.h>`, C++'s `<assert.h>` lacks it as well. The only possible omission is that [depr.c.headers]p2 appears to import the `std`-namespace names, but nothing else. `assert` is a macro but should be defined by `<assert.h>` as well.

Comment: @hvd:  Are you referring to the paragraph that begins: "The header <complex.h> behaves as if..." ?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Sorry for the confusion, no, I'm referring to "Every other C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if [...]", which used to be p2 (with less wording), but is now p3.

Comment: @hvd:  Ok.  I think you're reading too much into that paragraph.  20.2 [library.c] introduces the C library and defers to the C standard for the detailed specification of those headers.  20.5.1.2 [headers]/p4 "Except as noted in..." pretty much says the opposite, defining the cname headers in terms of the name.h headers as specified in the C standard library.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Again you're treating C's `<xxx.h>` and C++'s `<xxx.h>` as the same. They're not. C++'s `<xxx.h>` is like C++'s `<cxxx>`, except for namespace, which are both different from C's `<xxx.h>`. 20.2 covers C++'s `<xxx.h>`. 20.5.1.2 refers to C's `<xxx.h>`. There's no contradiction. For a case where it matters: C++'s `<cstdlib>` adds overloads of `abs`. Those overloads are also visible even if only `<stdlib.h>` is included. Try it online to see how implementations treat it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/515f21d12ce5f2ad

Answer (score 10):

**Looking at code:**

```
Using assert.h   // Compatible with C language standard
---------------
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    assert(true == true); // Execution continues
    assert(true == false); // Execution will abort with false value assert!
    return 0;
}

Using cassert    // Not compatible with C language standard
--------------
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    assert(true == true); // Execution continues
    assert(true == false); // Execution will abort with false value assert!
    return 0;
}
```

**They both work!**

---

**Which one is better in C++11?**

**Regarding [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)'s and [C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4660.pdf)'s specification:**

> **C.5.1** (section from C++17 document)
>   **Modifications to headers [diff.mods.to.headers]**
>
> 1. For compatibility with the C standard library, the C++ standard library provides the C headers enumerated in D.5, but their use is
>      deprecated in C++.
> 2. There are no C++ headers for the C headers , `<stdnoreturn.h>`, and `<threads.h>`, nor are the C headers themselves
>      part of C++.
> 3. The C++ headers  (D.4.1) and  (D.4.4), as well as their corresponding C headers  and , do not
>      contain any of the content from the C standard library and instead
>      merely include other headers from the C++ standard library.

---

> **D.5** 
>   **C standard library headers [depr.c.headers]** 
>   1. For compatibility with the C standard library, the C++ standard  library provides the C headers shown in Table 141.

[image]

Both **C++11** and **C++17** standard specifications documents state the use of `<X.h>` remains for compatibility with the C standard, although their use is regarded as **deprecated**.

---

**Regarding the [C++ 20 standard proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r0.html#3.5)**

They are reviewing **"undeprecating"** the use of the C library headers in C++20. `<X.h>` appear highlighted in green. C++11 and C++17 deprecation, as of now, is stated as a **"weak recommendation"** and a "tweak" for keeping the "**C standard library headers (c.headers)**" is displayed below:

> **"The basic C library headers are an essential compatibility feature, and not going anywhere anytime soon."** (from [C++ 20 review document](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r0.html#3.5))

---

> **D.5 C standard**
>   **library headers [depr.c.headers]**
>
> **Weak recommendation:** In addition to the above, also remove the
>   corresponding C headers from the C++ standard, much as we have no
>   corresponding `<stdatomic.h>`, `<stdnoreturn.h>`, or `<threads.h>`, headers.
>   As above, but with the following tweaks:
>   20.5.5.2.1 C standard library headers [c.headers]
>
> For compatibility with the C standard library, the C++ standard
>   library provides the C headers shown in Table 141. Table 141 — C
>   headers

```
 <assert.h>  <inttypes.h>   <signal.h>      <stdio.h>   <wchar.h>
 <complex.h> <iso646.h>     <stdalign.h>    <stdlib.h>  <wctype.h>
 <ctype.h>   <limits.h>     <stdarg.h>      <string.h>  
 <errno.h>   <locale.h>     <stdbool.h>     <tgmath.h>
 <fenv.h>    <math.h>       <stddef.h>      <time.h>
 <float.h>   <setjmp.h>     <stdint.h>      <uchar.h>
```

> The header `<complex.h>`
>   behaves as if it simply includes the header . 
>   The header `<tgmath.h>` behaves as if it simply includes the headers `<complex>` and `<cmath>`.

---

> **[Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/compat_short.pdf)** recommends **maximising inter-operability** between
>   the **C and C++ languages**, by **reducing imcompatibilities** as much as
>   possible. Others argue otherwise, as it complicates things.

So, it seems `<X.h>` aren't **going anywhere**. Ultimately, you can use both.  Personally, I would make the decision of which one I would use boil  down to having your code **backwards compatible with C code** or not.

Comment: where did you get that `<cX> headers already use and include <X.h> headers`? [<cX> headers just puts things in `std` namespace, and optionally in global namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32606280/995714), [cstdio stdio.h namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10460277/995714)

Comment: *"As <cX> headers already use and include <X.h> headers."* - This may be a common implementation that you've run into a lot, but it's not really a correct general statement. Nothing says that has to be the case. I mean, I'm looking at mingw's `<cmath>` right now and [it does a lot more than just include `math.h`](http://pastebin.com/zSr81wD3). Other than that I don't see any real problems with this answer's wording.

Comment: @Sjoerd, are you contributing to C++20?

Comment: @JasonC the <cX> headers are not required to include <X.h> because they're not required to put things in the global namespace, although many do. OTOH <X.h> are not required to put things in std namespace

Comment: This answer has been cloned to the original question, so its value here seems limited.  I suggest deleting this one and letting people find the other via the duplicate question link.

Comment: This was the original Q&A...